# Use variable inside this constant declared in angular services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constants, angular-services

I have this constant `webroot` declared inside my angularjs v1 services.

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
    .value('version', '0.1')
    .constant('configuration',
        {
            webroot: 'http://127.0.0.1:10840'
        }
])
```

I have a variable `port` for port number used by `webroot`. I want to use `port` to declare the constant `webroot` in a way that looks like something below;

```
let port = 10840;

    angular.module('myApp.services', [])
        .value('version', '0.1')
        .constant('configuration',
            {
                webroot: 'http://127.0.0.1:' + port
            }
    ])
```

How can this be done in angular v1?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38366461/6449750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do that. Here is a sample demo

```js
let port = 10840;
angular.module("app",[])
.value('version', '0.1')
.constant('configuration',
    {
        webroot: 'http://127.0.0.1:' + port
    }
)
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,configuration){
 console.log(configuration.webroot)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

</div>
```